# What's with suphp?

Tags: php, php5, suphp

I inherited a web server running Apache/PHP on a CentOS 5 machine.  This is a hosted server so I am still familiarizing myself with the environment.  There is really no user activity on this machine, yet in "top", I constantly see php processes popping up and closing.  While the php process is alive, I see it taking up 40% of cpu or so.  I noticed a log file called "suphp_log" and notice it is being written to every 3 or 4 seconds with entries like:

```
[Thu Oct 21 02:56:34 2010] [info] Executing "/home/user/public_html/index.php" as UID 511, GID 511
[Thu Oct 21 02:56:35 2010] [info] Executing "/home/user/public_html/index.php" as UID 511, GID 511
[Thu Oct 21 02:56:37 2010] [info] Executing "/home/user/public_html/index.php" as UID 511, GID 511
[Thu Oct 21 02:56:40 2010] [info] Executing "/home/user/public_html/index.php" as UID 511, GID 511
[Thu Oct 21 02:56:44 2010] [info] Executing "/home/user/public_html/index.php" as UID 511, GID 511
[Thu Oct 21 02:56:44 2010] [info] Executing "/home/user/public_html/index.php" as UID 511, GID 511
[Thu Oct 21 02:56:47 2010] [info] Executing "/home/user/public_html/index.php" as UID 511, GID 511
```

I am not that familiar with suphp but is there some configuration setting or something that causes it to constantly read the index.php file or something?  How do I control the configuration of suphp?  I assume this is where the load on my system is coming from.  What can I do about this?

Comment: It is the other way around when the index is called apache logs it to the file as to the index not being used, use the server-status to verify who and from where it is being accessed on check the access_log file. How to enable the server-status check http://serverfault.com/questions/174038/how-can-i-figure-out-which-site-on-my-server-is-getting-swamped-with-traffic/174057#174057

Answer (score 1):

suPHP wouldn't be doing this on it's own. There should be some event that is causing the webserver to provide index.php via the suPHP module. What do the access logs say ?

Comment: Nothing being written to the access log when this is happening.

Comment: If I disable suphp and just make php a dso call, then I still see httpd processes taking cpu.  Again, however, no entries in the access logs.  Very strange.